# Add a new column to a pandas dataframe if the corresponding item in the previous column is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe which looks similar to the following:

```
    X       Y
0  21    left_hey
1  43   hello
2  54  center
3  12     you front
4  64    jack
5  76     roy
6  42    back
```

And a list:

```
words = ['center', 'back', 'right', 'left', 'front']
```

MRE for dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [21, 43, 54, 12, 64, 76, 42],
    'Y': ['left_hey', 'hello', 'center', 'you front', 'jack', 'roy', 'back']
})
```

Now I want to insert another column in `df` (say `Z`). The elements in `Z` would depend on the corresponding element in `Y`. If the substring in `Y` matches any word in `words` insert `1` in `Z` and `0` otherwise.

So my expected output should look like:

```
    X           Y  Z
0  21  left hello  1
1  43       hello  0
2  54      center  1
3  12   you front  1
4  64        jack  0
5  76         roy  0
6  42        back  1
```

Now I know that I could use the method `Series.str.contains(word)`, but I don't seem to figure out how to pass all the elements from `words` at the same time and match the substring with `Y`, I've also tried to use `any()` but it returns `boolean`.

Also I could loop through `words` and explicitly match each word but that would be really slow if the dataframe is large (as my use-case).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask and then are 3 ways for mapping `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
df['Z'] = df.Y.isin(words).astype(int)
df['Z'] = df.Y.isin(words).view('i1')
df['Z'] = np.where(df.Y.isin(words),1,0)
```

EDIT: If need test subtrings:

```
df['Z'] = df.Y.str.contains('|'.join(words)).astype(int)
df['Z'] = df.Y.str.contains('|'.join(words)).view('i1')
df['Z'] = np.where(df.Y.str.contains('|'.join(words)),1,0)
```

Comment: Woah, thanks for the lightning fast answer. You're so much familiar:)

Comment: One more question though, what if there is an element in `Y` as `center_back` or `back_place` and I want to put 1 in `Z` for it. Like if the word in list matches a fragment of word in `Y` I would mark it as 1.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel - Then use `df['Z'] = df.Y.str.split('_', expand=True).isin(words).any(axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: @YashvanderBamel - I got it, added to answer